# Is it permitted to share a plate or bowl with a pet (such as a cat or dog)?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, animals

Is it permitted to use the same plates and bowls to feed a pet cat or dog which are also used for eating?

Assuming the pet is fed kosher (for humans) food is this permitted?

Are there any issues with sharing with an animal or their saliva rendering the utensil unkosher?

If so/not, what are the sources of this?

Comment: I'm assuming you don't mean sharing plates without washing them... right?

Comment: Can you explain why you think a non-food item (saliva) on a cold dish would render the dish "unkosher?" I can't think of any - dirt isn't treif, it's just dirt.

Comment: I don't know if this is something that I would want to do, myself, even after washing the dish. But, consider what the Torah itself, perhaps, implies. How often have our ancestors taken water from a well, lake, or water trough, etc. where animals have drunk from previously? For all we know, they may have drawn water from the well or trough at the same time that the animals were drinking from it! I can't see the case of your dish being any more halachically severe than this. I've seen a few of my (rather weird) friends have their dog lick meat off their dinner plate at the dinner table!

Comment: I should have added that the plates would be cleaned before we eat off them again and its not something I like to in the first place but in a house with young children and a dog... Well, it can happen. :)

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Good question. I suppose saliva "feels" treyf as the product of a non-kosher animal?

Comment: Also, I wondered if there was any requirement to eat separately for other reasons. (Apart from the requirement to feed pets before ourselves of course.)

Comment: Not sure if it counts as a "product" or "by-product." It's certainly not likely to be considered a food to be among the ***ma'achalos*** *asuros*...